# Make Merge Files the default behavior in (High Sierra) Finder when moving folders?

Tags: finder, folders, copy-paste, macos

MacOS notoriously deletes whole duplicate folders when you are moving folders. That is, if you have a file structure:

```
Folder1
└── Photos
    ├── Bright\ Selfie.jpg
    ├── Indiana\ Dunes\ at\ Sunset.JPG
    └── Me\ &\ Mom\ (2).jpg
Folder2
└── Photos
    ├── 8-9-1942.jpg
    ├── 8-9-1942.psd
    └── 8334455046_81356161e5_b.jpg
```

And we drag `Folder2/Photos` into Folder1, you'll get a window that says:

[image: "Okay if I delete all of your files?]
And if you select `Replace` thinking, "Surely, it will sensibly merge my two folders," it will happily delete ALL of the files in `Folder1/Photos`. Interestingly, Cmd-Z doesn't updo the action either.

```
Folder1
└── Photos
    ├── 8-9-1942.jpg
    ├── 8-9-1942.psd
    └── 8334455046_81356161e5_b.jpg
Folder2
```

However, if you hold down `Option`/`Alt` while you drag-and-drop, you'll get a different alert:

[image: Okay, if you insist I'll do the sensible thing.]
And when you Merge, Finder only makes copies of your files, not moves them (which is the usual use of Opt-Drag-Drop):

```
Folder1
└── Photos
    ├── 8-9-1942.jpg
    ├── 8-9-1942.psd
    ├── 8334455046_81356161e5_b.jpg
    ├── Bright\ Selfie.jpg
    ├── Indiana\ Dunes\ at\ Sunset.JPG
    └── Me\ &\ Mom\ (2).jpg
Folder2
└── Photos
    ├── 8-9-1942.jpg
    ├── 8-9-1942.psd
    └── 8334455046_81356161e5_b.jpg
```

And if any of the files within these folders share a name, fogitaboutit. Finder simple "can't" merge these folders.

So two questions:

1. How do I actually *move* folders, merging any duplicate folders in Finder?
2. How do I make this the default behavior for Finder?

And yes, I know that there are options to `cp`, `mv`, `ditto`, and `tar` that do this sensibly on the command line.

Comment: Umm. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but are you asking how to move files (not copy but actually move), If so, hold down the command key and drag to move the files. The option key makes a copy of the file.

Comment: Okay, that's useful, but does it merge? I don't think so.